# is p2p0 a wireless interface for WIFI DIRECT in android?

Tags: java, android, networking, network-programming, wifi

when i print all interfaces in my android device:

```
03-10 19:50:15.484: I/System.out(22415): lo
03-10 19:50:15.494: I/System.out(22415): upnlink0
03-10 19:50:15.504: I/System.out(22415): svnet0
03-10 19:50:15.504: I/System.out(22415): rmnet0
03-10 19:50:15.514: I/System.out(22415): rmnet1
03-10 19:50:15.524: I/System.out(22415): rmnet2
03-10 19:50:15.534: I/System.out(22415): sit0
03-10 19:50:15.544: I/System.out(22415): ip6tnl0
03-10 19:50:15.554: I/System.out(22415): p2p0
03-10 19:50:15.564: I/System.out(22415): wlan0
```

i wounder if p2p0 is the actual interface for WIFI DIRECT? also how to print just the currently used INTERFACES ??

Answer (score 0):

p2p0 is the interface for WIFI DIRECT.

Send 'ifconfig' command in android studio console to see currently used INTERFACES.
If any interface is used currently then the status shows active otherwise it shows inactive.