# Android NetworkInterface. What are the meanings of names of NetworkInterface?

Tags: android, network-interface

I want to get available network of the current device, so I firstly get networkinterfaces list:

```
NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
```

Then, iterate every one:

```
NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
String name = intf.getName();
```

Here is the problem. The names of returned value of 'name' are: rmnet_data1, dymmy0, wlan0, rmnet_usb0, intf, lo, p2p0, sit0. (on my device) I want to know what are the meanings of them.

Comment: you forgot to include Cross Core Modem Network Interface(ccmni) : ccmni0 / ccmni1
which are basically interfaces for cellular data.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Since Android is based on Linux, Linux network interface naming patterns apply to Android devices.

Here's some resources on *nix network interface naming

- [a tour of classic Linux network interface names](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/nag2/x-087-2-hwconfig.tour.html)
- [new predictable interface names](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/)
- [a good StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24962329/what-is-an-interface-identifier)

To summarize:

`lo` usually stands for the loopback interface (localhost)

`wlan` usually stands for a wireless networking interface

`rmnet` interfaces are usually associated with [cellular connections and usb tethering](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm/+/android-msm-flo-3.4-kitkat-mr1/Documentation/usb/gadget_rmnet.txt)

`sit` interfaces are associated with [tunneling IPv6 over IPv4](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/tunneling#SIT_tunnels)

`p2p` interfaces are usually associated with peer-to-peer connections (perhaps your Android device's [WiFi Direct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324889/is-p2p0-a-wireless-interface-for-wifi-direct-in-android) support?)

`dummy` interfaces provide [special aliases for the loopback interface](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/nag/node72.html)

Comment: This is a really comprehensive guide, although is short. For instance, I didn't know that P2P is related to WiFi-direct!

Answer (score 1):

`ap` or `swlan` interfaces (depending on the Android distribution) can be found when the Mobile Hotspot (Access Point) is activated on an Android device. It might also be associated with a regular `wlan` interface though (observed on devices where it is not possible to activate the WiFi connection and Mobile Hotspot at the same time, e.g. Android 9 on Galaxy Tab S2).